# REST api: how bad idea is it to pass a new value as a url query string in PATCH method?

Tags: rest

I had to create the implementation of a PATCH method, because of the need to update only a single value.

I spend too much time wandering is there any way to only pass the single value, instead of a whole request body.

And I've got the feeling that it is bad idea to pass it as a url query param, but why? Can someone explain if and why it is a bad idea, for example, to try and update the age of a customer like this:

```
PATCH host/api/customers/{id}?newAge=45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I've got the feeling that it is bad idea to pass it as a url query param

Yes, it is.

> but why?

Because the target-uri in the request identifies the document (resource) that we are taking about, not the change that we want to make to that document.

In other words, as far as a general purpose component is concerned, in the same way that

```
/host/api/customers/{id}
/host/api/customers/{id}/newAge/45
```

identify different resources, so too do

```
/host/api/customers/{id}
/host/api/customers/{id}?newAge=45
```

In other words, both the path *and the query part* are part of the "identifier", see [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#appendix-B), [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.3).

---

[RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) describes one setting where your proposal is likely to cause a problem: cache-invalidation.  Because the target-uri is the primary cache key, a general purpose cache will not recognize that

```
GET /host/api/customers/{id}
PATCH /host/api/customers/{id}?newAge=45
```

are two requests about the same object, and that the copy of the document we cached after the first request is no longer valid after the second succeeds.

If we were modifying this resource via forms on the web, we would use a request like

```
POST /host/api/customers/{id} HTTP/2.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

newValue=45
```

And because the identifiers match, general purpose caches can do the right thing by just following the standard.

---

Update 2022-07-11: the current standard for cache invalidation is [RFC-9111](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-invalidating-stored-respons)

Comment: thanks! this is the kind of answer I was hoping for!